# Child theme not activating despite success message

Tags: themes, child-theme

I'm struggling to activate a child theme on my WordPress. I tried with this combination:

style.css

```css
/*
Theme Name: test child
Template: parent-theme-directory-name
Version: 1.0.1
*/
```

functions.php

```php
<?php
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function () {
    wp_enqueue_style('parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
});
```

I get a success message: "New theme activated.", but the theme is not activated. Instead, it activates the first theme found in the directory listing.

Tried to activate this child on two different WP installations and two different themes.
Running latest WP multisite with PHP 7.4. Also, all plugins are deactivated.

I could successfully "network enable" the theme and it's data is correctly displayed in themes.php

Comment: Is it a child theme of the one that is active?

Comment: No. It activates a theme that is not even a parent of any theme. It's name is just first in alphabetical order. When I made another child theme of that theme, problem persisted as well.

Comment: The codex offers two different methods for enqueuing parent styles - can you check the second one: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/#3-enqueue-stylesheet